# Send pdf jasper straight to the printer in web app

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need to send a pdf jasper directly to the printer, the current code PDF is delegated to the browser and therefore the user can print as many copies as desired. Must allow only print one copy, so I thought I'd send directly to printing.
I searched the forum but did not understand what would be the best solution to the issue.

Take a look at my code:

```
public class UtilRelatorios {

public static void imprimeRelatorio(String relatorioNome,
        HashMap parametros) throws IOException, JRException {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ServletContext context = (ServletContext) fc.getExternalContext().getContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = 
                JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                        context.getRealPath("/relatorios")+ File.separator+relatorioNome+".jasper",
                        parametros);    
        //int finalPag = jasperPrint.getPages().size();
        //System.out.println("page: "+finalPag);
        //JasperPrintManager.printPage(jasperPrint,finalPag,false);
        byte[] b = null;
        //JasperPrintManager.printPage(jasperPrint, 0, false);

        try {
            b = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }    

            if (b != null && b.length > 0) {
                // Envia o relatório em formato PDF para o browser
                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                int codigo = (int) (Math.random()*1000);
                response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline);filename=relatorio_"+codigo+".pdf");
                response.setContentLength(b.length);
                ServletOutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();
                ouputStream.write(b, 0, b.length);
                ouputStream.flush();
                ouputStream.close();
            }   
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If as seems in question you like to send the report **directly** to user's printer via **web application**, `browser`.

This can **not** be done!, you **can not** control the web users printer directly from the browser (excluding the use of activeX or other home made plugins)

*Probably this is luck since otherwise while navigating on internet you would have people printing alot of advertising on your printer....*

If instead you like to send it to a printer **attached to server**, this can be done!

If its the server printer please let me know and I can pass you some code.

Comment: I want to send directly to the default printer on the client machine.
Since I can not control it via your browser, thought otherwise:

* The user clicks print
* Unless the pdf into a temporary folder
* Sent to the default printer and then exclude the directory file

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Do only way to ensure that user only prints one time would be that you develop some kind of activeX or other plugin... java web start...

Comment: I developed an applet for printing the report but I can not run in the browser gives the error not supported plugin, you can help me on the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735509/applet-running-in-chrome

Comment: Search for NPAPI (you need to enable it in the chrome browser)

Answer (score 0):

If the client &  server PC  are on the same network ie LAN, you can share the client's printer on the server, then send report  to it just like you'd send to a locally installed printer.

Comment: But that does not help the OP at all