# Applet running in Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, applet

I need to run an applet in the browser because the issue [Send pdf jasper straight to the printer in web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542801/send-pdf-jasper-straight-to-the-printer-in-web-app)

The applet is working but I can not run it in Chrome the message plugin not supported.

[Versão 46.0.2490.86 m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU8iR.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Serviço de Impressão</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
        <object data="Imprimir.jar"  type="application/x-java-applet" width="400px" 
        height="740px" >
        </object>       
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check otu this.  https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/launching_web_start_applications or check settings in chrome NPAPI

Comment: Yes, @PetterFriberg suggestion of using JWS to launch the applet free-floating would be best, especially because of this.. https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml  **Chrome no longer supports NPAPI (technology required for Java applets)**  (it is referring to applets embedded in a web page)